# Typical behavior and habits via the present simple and "will"

Tags: tense

The sentence

> She'll sit talking to herself for hours.

may express typical behavior. Indeed, M. Swan in his *Practical English Usage* (629.7) says: "We can use *will* to talk about typical behavior" (habits and characteristics).

But we can also use the present simple to express one. For instance:

> She sits talking to herself for hours.

What's the difference between expressing of typical behavior via *will* and the present simple?

Comment: @snailboat Sure, it was a typo. I'm sorry.

Comment: No need to apologize, just trying to help :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*The Cambridge Grammar Of The English Language* (p194) lists this function of *will* as expressing "*propensity*", and gives the example: *He will lie in bed all day, reading trashy novels*.

The CGEL goes on to explain:

> Here we are concerned with characteristic or habitual behavior ...  A 
>   simple present could be substituted with little effect. ... Strong stress
>   on the auxiliary conveys the speaker's emotive response to the
>   situation - usually exasperation, disapproval, resignation, or the
>   like: *He WILL pour tea-leaves down the sink*.

So, both *She'll sit talking to herself for hours* and *She sits talking to herself for hours* will likely be interpreted as simple statements of fact, whereas *She **will** sit talking to herself for hours* will be taken as conveying the speaker's (usually negative) evaluation of that fact.

Answer (score 0):

The "will" usage has also been mentioned in Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English as "annoying habit":

used to describe someone’s habits, especially when you think they are annoying, e.g.

Trish will keep asking damn silly questions.

Comment: The following URL says "We can use 'will' to describe present habits and behaviour whether it is good or bad." So is it for only annoying habits? http://www.ecenglish.com/learnenglish/lessons/describing-habits

Comment: @243: "will" is used for talking about habits in general. However, if you put extra emphasis on this word, it means that the habit annoys you.